# How to find proxy settings used with MATE Terminal or via a web browser

Tags: networking, wireless, proxy

I'm on a virtualized environment and it has no network manager, as the network settings are pre-defined. I would just like to see the network configuration, not modify it.

MATE Terminal shows this for ifconfig

```
bash-4.2$ ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 00:25:90:23:11:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xfbce0000-fbd00000  

Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
```

any solutions as to preview network settings, proxies enabled, etc?
If it requires installing any programs, please include a step by step how to install to.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to System --> Preferences --> Other ---> Network Proxy on Ubuntu Mate 15.04